# getting and using textbox text and changing its color by html select box

Tags: javascript, html

```
function Start(){
    var headerr = document.getElementById("pageh").value;
    var hcolor = document.getElementById("hcolor").value;
    var hsize = document.getElementById("hsize").value;

    document.body.innerHTML = "";
}
```

That's the JS code for taking the value of the textbox and the select boxes.

```
<tr>
    <td>page header</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="pageh" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Header color:</td>
    <td>
        <select id="hcolor">
            <option>red</option>
            <option>purple</option>
            <option>gray</option>
        </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Header size</td>
    <td>
        <select id="hsize">
            <option>small</option>
            <option>normal</option>
            <option>big</option>
        </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Send" onclick="Start()" /><input type="reset" value="Clear" /></td>
</tr>
```

And the HTML code for the textbox and the select boxes.
So what can I do for posting the text and manipulating its color and size?
I thought about using document.write(""headerr""); but it doesn't seem to work.

ETA JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7LNMn/

Thank you!!

Comment: You want to print out the results?

Comment: hey your function is not executing!

Answer (score 0):

```
function Start(){
    var headerr = document.getElementById("pageh").value;
    var hcolor = document.getElementById("hcolor").value;
    var hsize = document.getElementById("hsize").value;

    var g = document.getElementById("header"); // var g will store document.getElementById("header") so, i don't have to write much whereas header can be changed by the element's id e.g. header of website!
    g.style.background = hcolor; // here g will get the element and style its bg
    g.style.fontSize = hsize; // here its fontSize
    // and I dont know what to do with pageh variable!
}
```

Comment: It isnt working for me...
Is there another method for this?
The pageh is the title itself outcoming from the box when i click the button. And the js should set the title with the selected items from the form.

Comment: hey can you do it with jquery? its better and its working with it!

Comment: umm no i cant at this moment :S i know jquery but the class teacher wants me to make this bonus assigment with JS .. He told me to make a form with: header input, color of the header, size of the header, a paragraph for the site , color for the para, size for the para, check boxes for pictures(dint tought how to do that yet), and main site bg color also from drop list and a send and clear button.
If you can make me a thing like that i will apreciate it very much :S since i dont understand what to do and i dont want to embrace myself

Comment: woah ok i am doing it now!

Comment: http://jsbin.com/uzodew/2 style it according to your taste! and can change it as you like! and that checkboxes of image! I think your teacher wanted a bunch of images with some label describing something about image just add four images to your directory and add four checkboxes at the right and on submit function get all the checked checkboxes and if they 2 then add 2 images to left by js `document.getElementById("left").appendChild("<img src='any source here'>")` function!

Comment: Thank you so much! sry it took me so long to answer :\ I love you man